# How can I find the IP address of my stolen macbook?

Tags: networking, mac, ip

Someone stole my computer, and I know their location from Find My iPhone (they're using it right now), but I'm having a hard time learning their IP address. They aren't logged in on Dropbox or Gmail, so unfortunately I can't find it using those services.

Is there any way to use Find My iPhone to find the IP address? Any way at all?

Comment: Forget the IP, just call the police and tell them that you know the location of your stolen device

Comment: ^^ this. exactly. For some reason laptop theft victims often think it's a good idea to track down and mess with people who are clearly capable and willing to operate outside the law, to the extent of recommending breaking the law to recover property. Use the police, that's why you pay for them.

Comment: I filed a police report, but they said they wouldn't send people over there. It's at a bad area in Brooklyn. My laptop is covered by insurance, so I'd just like to get a couple things off of it that I don't have backed up. Finding out their IP address seems to be the easiest way to do that. After I do, I can wipe the computer clean using Find My iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the information goes from the App -> the "iCloud" -> your device that you're tracking from. So I don't see you getting the IP address from any of those (MITM seems out of the question in this case).

I would however recommend that you change any and all passwords that you have saved on there. Waiting for them to login to a server (which is the most viable option here) simply to retrieve their IP is a risk.

P.S.
Why exactly do you need their IP address if you have their location? **Go get your laptop.**